# Scala compiler for java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Do I need to add Scala Compiler Jar file to run Spark Sql in java(Eclipse)?

Are following these two jar files required?

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
<version>2.13.0-M4</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
<version>2.13.0-M4</version>
```

If I'm using java, then why do I need to have scala compiler?

Comment: What code are you running?

Comment: SparkSession spark =    SparkSession.builder().appName("my-spark-app").config("spark.some.config.option", "config-value").getOrCreate();

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a scala compiler, theres java Spark API for that , But you can use scala and I personally think its easier.

Im pretty sure you can do anything with spark in Java and its capabilities in java and scala are interchangeable

Comment: I'm getting following error in case I remove these two jars.
The type scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files